# How to echo array data using foreach() in php?

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array like the one below given. I want to echo this elements one by one. Expected output also added with the post

```
$myArray => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['id'] => 1
                    ['name'] => "Amla"
                    ['age'] => 25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['id'] => 2
                    ['name'] => "Kallis"
                    ['age'] => 35
            )
       )
```

// expected output

```
1  Amla  25
2  Kallis 35
```

My code:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
    echo "$myArray[$key]=>$value"."</br>";
    }
```

Comment: please refer to the PHP Manual on arrays and foreach. This is trivial to solve on your own.

Comment: use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple approach.  Add css to the spans if you want.

```
 foreach($my_array as $item):
      echo '<span>'.$item['id'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$item['name'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$item['age'].';</span>';
 endforeach;
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
foreach ($myArray  as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```php
<?php
    foreach($my_array as $item) {
        echo $item['id'], " ", $item['name'], " ", $item['age'];
    }
?>
```

You can edit the format of the output with CSS. Please note that I use commas instead of dots for the `echo()`: it's faster to call the function multiple times than concatenate.

Sources:

http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/output-in-php/

http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=27423.0